# Where do I find meat for the hidden merchant?

Tags: evoland

I've found a hidden merchant on the overworld map in a tent northwest from Aogai Village. He said he needs meat so he can sell me his items.

Where's that meat he's talking about?

[image: Hidden merchant location]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There seems to be a random Chokobo that you can kill for raw meat, but he wants it cooked.  Still trying to figure out how to cook it. I got the encounter with the chokobo just north of the first town.

**Edit**

After killing a chokobo in the northern plain, you'll have to talk the the lady near the well in Aogai (the one with a roof, not the one near the expensive merchant and the overactive kid) so she'll cook it and you'll be able to give it the to merchant. It will give you :

> An extra heart (health)

Comment: The old lady who had the bombs in her cellar, but wanted you to kill a dragon will cook the meat for you in Aogai.

Comment: Just delivered the meat.  All they give you is a heart container.